# UDP recvfrom not successful

Tags: c, sockets, udp, dhcp

I am trying to write DHCP client, but failing to receive the DHCP Offer due to **"Resource temporarily unavailable"** on recvfrom(). I set my socket like so (leaving out the checks for return values):

```
    int sct = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    return sct;
    /* set option for socket to broadcast */
    int opt_val = 1;    
    int res = setsockopt(sct, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&opt_val, sizeof(opt_val));    
    res = setsockopt(sct, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, (char *)&opt_val, sizeof(opt_val));
```

Then I bind to the socket to the interface and then the actuall bind itself. All success. Then I send DHCP Discover with sucess and I fail to catch DHCP Offer. Shows up in WIreshark. Receiving the packet like so:

```
struct sockaddr_in srcInfo;
struct timeval t_out;
t_out.tv_usec = timeout * 10000; // 50 ms timeout
t_out.tv_sec = 0;
socklen_t sockSize = sizeof(srcInfo);
int setSc = setsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char*)&t_out, sizeof(struct timeval));
ssize_t res = recvfrom(socket, (void*)buffer, sizeof(DHCP_hdr), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&srcInfo, &sockSize);
```

The res var is always -1 and the error is as written above. I have tried everything that is here on SO - no success. Using `FD_SET` with `FD_ISSET`. Setting the socket as nonblocking, calling recvfrom right after that again. Always getting the same error.

Comment: Depending on the platform, after a socket function returns an error, there's usually another global variable value, such as `err` or `errno`, or a function to call, such as `WSAGetLastError()`, which has a specific error code.

Comment: `sizeof(DHCP_hdr)` is this large enough for a complete reply packet ?

Comment: @wildplasser yes it is, it is, exactly 590 bytes

Comment: @DanKorn yep,"Resource temporarily unavailable" is a human redable form of the `errno` after unsuccessful `recvfrom()`

Comment: What is the value for errno? I mean EAGAIN, EBADF, EINTR, etc...

Comment: @AlejandroVisiedo value 11, EAGAIN

Comment: Any firewall rule that can be filtering the traffic before it arrive to your application? If you are using some firewall, test to disable it.

Comment: 10,000 μS is not '50mS', it is *ten* milliseconds, and both ten mS and 50mS are far too short for a network timeout. It should be measured in seconds, if not tens of seconds.

Comment: @EJP timeout is 5 thats why it is 50ms in total. The fact is - when I try to  set timeout higher than 2 secons, the `setsockopt()` fails to do so. (returns -1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Resource temporarily unavailable" corresponds to `EAGAIN`. The Errors section of `man recvfrom` says that `EAGAIN` is set if:

> a receive timeout had been set, and the timeout expired before data were received.

Your timeout seems to be too short.

According to [RFC 1541](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1541), the client may retransmit the discover message no sooner than 4 seconds after the initial message has been transmitted. It implies that a reasonable timeout shall be in that ballpark.

Comment: The timeout is sufficient, since acc to wireshark, the offer is sent in 25ms. I did raise the timeout anyway, but it doesnt help

Comment: @Coolman The error you are getting does not agree with you. You are arguing with the error itself.

Comment: At the end the reason why it threw the error was that some other application was already catching all the responses.